# Sparql Endpoint Merging with 2 Sparql Endpoints

Tags: sparql, semantic-web

For a research homework I have to try to merge 2 Endpoints into a new one.

I've begun with 2 Open Data Endpoint like WikiData and DBpedia (with Wikipedia)

As Article I've chosen Barack Obama.

Now my Code for WikiData is ok, I've tested it on their SPARQL Query.

```sql
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>.    
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>.    

SELECT * WHERE { ?p wdt:P26 wd:Q76. }
```

So how should I go further?

My target is to take both endpoints, see that both endpoints include that Obama his spouse is Michele and get this information in a new endpoint where this information is in.

So overall to get some endpoints and merge all together to one endpoint where everything from the endpoints in.

Anyone got an idea?

Would be great if you got some coding and some explanation to the code.

Comment: Your question is unclear. So far, your query just returns the spouse of Barack Obama from Wikidata. Ok. And now? You want to do the same on DBpedia? And then? What means "merge"? An RDF dataset consist of a set of RDF triples, so you'd have to get proper RDF triples from the endpoints, or not? SPARQL `CONSTRUCT` is the query type to use in that case

Comment: Next question, into which endpoint do you want to "merge" (whatever merge means...) the triples? Do you have a local triple store? If so, you want to load 2 triples into the triple store? What would be the purpose of having 2 triples with different URIs inside your endpoint? You'd also have to to entity linking to find RDF resources representing the same real world entity.

Comment: Yes now the same on DBpedia.

After this, how could i load this answer from my queries into a local triple store?

Comment: Well, I guess you you're missing fundamental things. Look at your query, it return exactly one single result which is the spouse of Barack Obama. **How** do you want to load this into a triple store? A triple store contains **proper RDF triples**, so you need subject, predicate and object. Do you understand this?

Comment: For DBpedia, I mean it's the same as for the Wikidata query - how did you generate this query? Just copy/paste I guess? In general, look at the DBpedia entry for Barack Obama, or not? There you can see the property you need. [click](http://dbpedia.org/page/Barack_Obama)

Comment: Yeah i know what RDP Triples are.

So my basic idea was to create a empty endpoint. So ill load from a open data endpoint (like wikidata) all data from barack obama into this endpoint. Now next i would like to get to the next endpoint and only get "new" triples in my local endpoint.

In DPPedia i dont understand what for selects i have to pick and the virtuoso query editor from dbpedia i also dont understand ^^

Sorry i'm little bite newby in sparql

Comment: *"all data from barack obama"* - your query does **not** return all data for Barack Obama. It just return the URI of his spouse. Sorry to say that, but Wikidata and DBpedia use **different URIs for the same entities** - so how do you want to find out what's "new" ?

Comment: And I already showed you the link to Barack Obama on DBpedia: http://dbpedia.org/resource/Barack_Obama - it shows all the data about him. This means, in the SPARQL query he has to be the subject and then you need the property for spouse which will be the predicate of the triple pattern

Comment: Yeah i know that its only the spouse, is only a test if i code properly.

Can you show me a code where i get the same result as above in DBPedia?

Yeah you right, i dont remind that that they use different URIs. So is my idea possible? That must be a program that analyse all triples and check if they could be the same or not, that would be a huge projekt!^^

Comment: I'm still not sure whether you even understood your query ... Why isn't Barack Obama the subject of the triple pattern? And for DBpedia it's the same, just use the other URIs. Why don't you look at the link I showed you twice now? the resource is `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Barack_Obama`, the property is obviously `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/spouse` as you can see if you finally open the link in your browser. The rest of the query is straightforward, subject, predicate object. And this will just return the spouse of course...and no RDF triples ...

Comment: *"That must be a program that analyse all triples and check if they could be the same or not"* - that's research topic and called *entity linking* - it's non-trivial.

Comment: OK ,i understood, just changing the URIs and then should that work :D

Entity Linking, do you have good sites to read in it?

Comment: http://www.ontologymatching.org/ is probably the most common entry into that area. Well known tool for instance matching (what you'd mostly need) are Silk and LIMES. Note, for linking Wikidata and DBpedia, you could make use of the existing `owl:sameAs` and `owl:equivalentProperty` data in DBpedia dataset.